# docker tail -n not showing correct no. of lines

Tags: docker, logging, tail

If I run the following docker tail command:

```
docker logs --tail all    8f8df1de5f9c |& wc -l
645
```

It reports 645 lines

If I then run:

```
docker logs --tail 645    8f8df1de5f9c |& wc -l
550
```

It shows a reduced no. of lines.

I would have expected both commands to show the same no. of lines?

P.S.
I'm writing unit tests so I need to know how many lines are available and then I need to run the command requesting exactly that no. of lines.

The docker version is:

docker --version
Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46

I'm running on ubuntu 20.04 with a zfs file system.

Comment: You surely miss some information in the question as the behavior could not be reproducible with my local container.

Comment: I don't know what I've missed. I've just tried it with another random container and go the same discrepancy.  docker logs --tail all    6e048e42bca0 |& wc -l
3591
docker logs --tail 3591    6e048e42bca0 |& wc -l
3570

Comment: @atline I've added the docker version.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read 250 line of file you must write this command

```
tail -n 250 pageName.blade.php
```

Comment: Could you add a documentation reference?